# Can you disable tabs in SemanticUI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui

It's possible disable a tab on [semantic-ui Tab](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/tab.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing

```
 <a class="item" data-tab="examples">Examples</a>
```

to

```
<span class="item disabled">Examples</span>
```

appears to do the trick.

Comment: thank you very much!
thanks! by show a example
and I'm sorry, for doubt your first answer.

Comment: @user2669011 If this answer helped you, please consider accepting it. You should see a checkmark next to it you can click.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is trying to disable tab with Semantic UI React using panes, this can be done by wrapping menuItem inside `<Menu.Item/>`.

```
const panes = [
  {
    menuItem: "Menu 1", // <-- a string
    render: () => (
      <Tab.Pane attached={false}>
        <Stuff1/>
      </Tab.Pane>
    ),
  },
  {
    menuItem: <Menu.Item disabled>Menu 2</Menu.Item>, // <-- a menu item
    render: () => (
      <Tab.Pane attached={false}>
        <Stuff2/>
      </Tab.Pane>
    ),
  },
];

return (
  <Tab
    fluid
    menu={{ secondary: true, pointing: true, widths: panes.length }}
    panes={panes}
  />
);
```